# Little-o notation for limits at zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, approximation

Very quick question which will help me clarify my understanding. Let's say I have an expression that uses little-o notation like the following
$$o_{h\to 0}(h)(1-h)+o_{h\to 0}(h)$$
Would I be correct in saying that this can be simplified like this:
$$o_{h\to 0}(h)(1-h)+o_{h\to 0}(h)=o_{h\to 0}(h)-o_{h\to 0}(h^2)+o_{h\to 0}(h)=o_{h\to 0}(h)-o_{h\to 0}(h^2)=o_{h\to 0}(h).$$
I suspect that this is true since when we take $h\to 0$, the $o_{h\to 0}(h^2)$ converges faster than $o_{h\to 0}(h)$?

Comment: It is best to use the definition of the little-o symbol and replace each occurrence of little-o with appropriate functions. Like here you can write the expression as $hf(h) (1-h)+hg(h)$ where $f(h), g(h) $ tend to $0$ with $h$.

Comment: It may be worth paying attention to the fact, that all the equalities, you have given, are, actually, at least, inclusions of one set of functions into another, or equalities between  sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be your expression. You could consider taking the absolute value of $E$ and use the triangle inequality to yield
$$\vert E \vert \leq o_{h \to 0}(h) + o_{h \to 0}(h + h^2) \leq o_{h \to 0}(h) + o_{h \to 0}(h^2) \leq \frac{c}{2} (h + h^2) \leq c h$$
for sufficiently small $h,$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}.$ Then of course $\vert E \vert = o_{h \to 0}(h).$ I hope this helps. :)